# How to add Google Authenticator to my website?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-authentication, two-factor-authentication

I have a web app that is Angular2 on the front-end and NodeJS on the back-end.  I want to allow clients to use Google Authenticator to make their accounts more secure.

How can I implement/use Google Authenticator in my website?  I cannot find an API to use or and tutorials to follow or any libraries to use.  Where can I find some resources to do this?

Comment: Just implement the ability to authenticate as user via a google account. That's all you can do. Whether the user will have to use the Authenticator depends on *their* account settings and will be different on a per-user basis.

Comment: @ChrisG Oh, so a client would only be able to use the Google Authenticator option if they have a google/gmail account?

Comment: No, but you tagged this with `google-authentication`, which is "all authentication using google accounts", so I assumed your question was about adding a gmail login to your web app.

Comment: I have reservations on Chris G's comment. Enabling sign-in with Google accounts is not all you can do. You can certainly develop MFA to your app's "built-in" accounts that works with an authenticating app like Google's or Microsoft's. Several sites are doing this and one I can think of at the moment is 500px.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The key phrase that you're looking for is "TOTP" (Time-Based One-time Password) - and it is a [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6238), rather than an API maintained by Google.

At a very high level, your backend will generate a secret that it will share with your users' Google Authenticator app. At login, both the Authenticator app and your backend with use the stored secret and current time to generate a single-use key. If the keys match, it means that the secrets match, and the user may be logged in.

The [SpeakEasy](https://github.com/speakeasyjs/speakeasy) node implementation seems to be pretty popular on github.

Comment: Speakeasy provides [sample codes](https://github.com/speakeasyjs/speakeasy/blob/master/README.md) for a JavaScript implementation. There is no communication with Google Authenticator - there is no need to, cf the TOTP specs linked by Andrew Rueckert above.

Comment: SpeakEasy seems to be abandoned project with their last update 6 years ago.

Comment: "NOT MAINTAINED"

Comment: Just google `TOTP <Language>`, and you'll have your pick of implementations. The [otplib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/otplib) NPM library looks like it can probably do what you want. It hasn't been updated in about a year, but the spec doesn't change, and the old code will still produce the correct 6-digit sequence.