# Google authenticator in my website

Tags: google-authenticator

I have used google authenticator, while I scan that code I can view it and continue my login,it is good. But if other users know my username and password also they can scan and get the code and they can also login. But I want to implement like google 2 step authentication, after knowing my username and password he can't login without my 2 step verification code. Can it possible for google authenticator?

Comment: Yes, have done exactly this myself.

Comment: But how we can implement such a manner that even if knowing the username and password can't login with google authenticator?. Only authenticator code will be shown against that particular user's phone.

Comment: That depends entirely on how your site is implemented and what you're using on the backend.

Comment: In backend I am using php with mysqli. But how I can manage it in the backend, I couldn't understand. Can you please give me some idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add Google Authenticator to my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44788632/how-to-add-google-authenticator-to-my-website)